# Orthogonal projection on space of tempered distribution $S'(\mathbb R)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, self-adjoint-operators

So let $S'(\mathbb R)$ be the space of tempered distributions, and let $\{e_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ be the family of Hermite functions (which are contained in the Schwartz space $S(\mathbb R)$).
Then I define the operator $P_m:S'(\mathbb R)\to S(\mathbb R)$ by the action
$$P_m\eta=\sum_{j=0}^m \langle e_j,\eta\rangle e_j$$
i.e. $P_m$ is the orthogonal projection on the span of $\{e_1,...,e_m\}$.
Clearly
$$\langle P_m\eta,\xi\rangle=\langle \eta,P_m\xi\rangle$$
for any $\xi,\eta\in S'(\mathbb R)$.

Is it correct to say that $P_m$ is a self-adjoint operator on $S'(\mathbb R)$?
I am confused since all the definitions of self-adjointness I've found involve the use of an inner product, and my functional analysis is a bit rusty.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should $\langle P_m\eta,\xi\rangle=\langle \eta,P_m\rangle$ read $\langle P_m\eta,\xi\rangle=\langle \eta,P_m\xi\rangle$?

Comment: Wrong use of words and notation is confusing. "self-adjoint" refers to operators $D\rightarrow H$ where $H$ is a Hilbert space and $D$ is a dense linear subspace of $H$. Now there is a notion of "transpose". If $R:V\rightarrow W$ is continuous linear map between topological vector spaces, one has a transpose map $R^t:W'\rightarrow V'$ between strong topological duals. Given that $(S')'$ is canonically isomorphic to $S$, it makes sense to ask if $P_m$ is equal to its transpose modulo that isomorphism...

Comment: ...I think the answer is yes. About notation: please use different notations for the $L^2$ inner product and for the duality pairing between distribution and test function. Using  $\langle\cdots\rangle$ for both is not helpful here.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam Thanks! Indeed I was not sure about the terminology , however I am not using two notation. In fact there's no $L^2$-inner product in the body of my question

Comment: I see. Then it's better to put the distribution on the left and test function on the right.